# C# thread safe class and list

Tags: c#

The current need is to pull many records from an SQL database and then submit those records in much smaller blocks to an API call. The volume of data pull from SQL is inconsistent based on how much data is loaded by another process and will sometimes be small enough to handle with only one worker. When the data pull is large (max 5k rows) it will require more threads to help query the API to obtain speed. The process works great but when I run one at a time it is slow at large volumes. However, I'm finding the list I pass to the class is changing as multiple threads are launched. How can I achieve thread safety?

I've read about this and tried at length - locks and ConcurrentBag for example but I'm not quite sure where to apply or how to use these to achieve what I am looking for.

Here is what I have:

```
class Start
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        SQLSupport sqlSupport = new SQLSupport();
        List<SQLDataList> sqlDataList = new List<SQLDataList>();
        List<SQLDataList> sqlAPIList = new List<SQLDataList>();
        sqlDataList = sqlSupport.sqlQueryReturnList<sqlDataList>("SELECT * FROM TABLE");

        if (sqlDataList.Count > 200)
        {
            int iRow = 0;
            int iRowSQLCount = 0;
            foreach (var item in sqlDataList)
            {
                if (iRowSQLCount == 100)
                {
                        APIProcess apiProcess= new APIProcess (sqlAPIList);
                        Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(apiProcess.Execute));
                        thr.Start();
                        sqlAPIList.Clear();
                        iRowSQLCount = 0;
                }

                sqlAPIList.Add(sqlDataList[iRow]);
                iRowSQLCount++;
                iRow++;
            }

        }
    }
}


class APIProcess
{
   List<SQLDataList> sqlAPIList= new List<SQLDataList>();  
   public APIProcess(List<SQLDataList> sqlList) 
   {
        sqlAPIList = sqlList;  
   }

   public void Execute()
   {
        foreach (var item in sqlAPIList)
        {
           //loop through the list, interact with the API, update the list and ultimately update SQL with the API data.
        }
   }
```

Comment: you can use BlockingCollection with single Consumer and multiple Producers some example you can find by the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-add-and-take-items